# Vue app hosted on netlify won't load on IE 11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, netlify, quasar

I have a vue app created with quasar cli. Everything works fine, but if I want to open my page in IE 11 it shows a white screen and never loads the content of the page (the q-app tag is empty). If I open the page via localhost it works. I have IE 11 support enabled in my browserslist. In all other browsers like chrome, firefox, opera and edge it works fine.
This is my site: https://roundtrips4you.de

Any Idea how to show the page normally in IE 11?

Comment: What is the version you're running in localhost, the dev version or prod version? Is it the same as the one you run in Internet? I check the website in IE and it has two errors in console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWCoe.png. I suggest you can use F12 dev tools to debug the website in IE to narrow down the issue. Besides, it could be better if you can provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the whole site.

Comment: Thats the dev version on localhost. Ok I will check it thanks.

Comment: You could check if it is also dev version in Internet. Feel free to come back if there's any update about the issue or you have any further questions.

Answer (score -1):

IE 11 does not support ES2015 and beyond. Also, IE11 support is [ditched by Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666) last August 17. There's also no workaround for your problem other than suggesting to use the latest Microsft browser in Edge or other browsers that support ES2015 and beyond.

Comment: IE11 doesn't support ES6+, but there are plenty of polyfills for compatibility. OP may need to look around at what specifically is causing the problem, but solutions like bluebird or createCustomElement worked for me. However, keep in mind that polyfills can make your browser run much slower.

Comment: @emoore yeah because polyfill only emulates certain APIs. Another thing the OP can do is transpile the code but transpiling means pain in maintaining code and no point on using JS frameworks that uses ES2015 and beyond syntax.